# jQuery validation to accept only three letters in a textbox

Tags: jquery, validation

This is my code.  I also want to add form validation so that it accepts only three letters.  Can any one help?

```
if ( unitBrief === "" ) {
    $("#divValidationMessageConfigurationTab").css('display' , 'inline');
    $("#spnValidationText").text("Unit Brief is required.");
    $(".unitBrief").focus();
    return;
}
```

Comment: you can set counter on keypress event http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: you want validation to be performed after pressing `enter key` or any `submit button` or right at the time you are typing in the input ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean like this?

```
if( ! /^[a-z]{3}$/i.test(unitBrief) ) { ... not 3 letters ... }
```

Comment: yes it worked only I had to give 3,4 so that it checks for maximum and min characters as well also I had to add ||(unitBrief.length!=3)

Comment: I didn't know you needed that from the question, but nvm; good that it worked

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only client side validation in your app (always validate on the server too!) then it'd look something like this:

```
$("#your_textbox").keypress(function() {
  var length = this.value.length;
  if(length >= MIN && length <= MAX) {
    $("#your_submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#your_validation_div").hide();
  } else {
    $("#your_submit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $("#your_validation_div").show();
  }
});
```

If you need a lot of validation in your application you might want to consider the [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

Setting the [maxlength attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_maxlength.asp):

```
<input type='text' maxlength="3" />
```